# Modern apis with FastAPI - Redis Caching

Tags: python-3.x, redis, fastapi

I'm trying to implement the redis caching in my API for the first time it is a simple fastapi application which is using openweather api to query some weather information and my intention is to cache each json response in the redis server. I'hve  made it to work with single key `city` but with this approach validating query parameters not working with the error handling I put in the place.

caching.py

```
import sys
from datetime import timedelta
import json

import redis

from services.openweather_service import get_report


def redis_connect() -> redis.client.Redis:
    try:
        client = redis.Redis(
            host="localhost",
            port=6379,
            db=0,
        )
        ping = client.ping()
        if ping is True:
            return client
    except redis.ConnectionError:
        print("Connection Error!")
        sys.exit(1)


client = redis_connect()


def get_routes_from_cache(key: str) -> str:
    """Data from redis."""

    val = client.get(key)
    return val


def set_routes_to_cache(key: str, value: str) -> bool:
    """Data to redis."""

    state = client.setex(
        key,
        timedelta(hours=24),
        value=value,
    )
    return state


async def route_optima(city: str, state: str, country: str, units=None) -> dict:

    location = {"city": city, "state": state, "country": country, "units": units}

    # First it looks for the data in redis cache
    data = get_routes_from_cache(key=json.dumps(location))
    # print(data)
    # print(type(data))

    # If cache is found then serves the data from cache
    if data is not None:
        data = data.decode("UTF-8")
        data_dict = json.loads(data)
        print(data_dict)
        print(type(data_dict))
        data["cache"] = True
        return data

    else:
        # If cache is not found then sends request to the OpenWeather API
        data = await get_report(city, state, country, units)

        # This block sets saves the respose to redis and serves it directly
        data["cache"] = False
        data = json.dumps(data)
        state = set_routes_to_cache(key=json.dumps(location), value=json.dumps(data))

        if state is True:
            return json.dumps(data)
        return data
```

Then I took a different approach by making the query params `location = {"city": city, "state": state, "country": country, "units": units}` as a key and the json response as a value but when app try to get the response from the cache here it got weird like right after passing the query params dict into the json.dumps it gives me the bytes object and so I decode it with `decode("utf-8")` but instead of coming back as a dict it gives me `<class 'str'>` type object. There I am lost... can anyone help me out here?

weather_api.py

```
from typing import Optional
import fastapi
from fastapi import Depends

from models.location import Location
from infrastructure.caching import route_optima
from models.validation_error import ValidationError

router = fastapi.APIRouter()


@router.get("/api/weather/{city}")
async def weather(loc: Location = Depends(), units: Optional[str] = "metric"):
    return await route_optima(loc.city, loc.state, loc.country, units)
```

And if I am using the wrong approach here then please point to the best approach to take here.

Answer (score 4):

As you are using Fastapi, it is better to use [aioredis](https://aioredis.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.0/api_reference.html) to leverage the async functionality.

Comment: I will give it a try. Thanks

Comment: Don't use aioredis. You will get pretty much everything aioredis has to offer and much more, using a better and far more reliable library [redis-py](https://github.com/redis/redis-py/)
Yep, you should use async libraries within FastAPI to get all its glory, and redis-py incorporates async support already (since version 4.2).

Comment: @YassineNacif this is a really nice, but could you elaborate more on why in redis main site there is this tutorial https://developer.redis.com/develop/python/fastapi/ that suggests using ```aioredis```, if there is already ```redis-py```? I don't quite get it.

Comment: @SeanWilliam There is nothing wrong by using `aioredis`. The thing is concern here is your preference. `aioredis` is popular, because it was one of the earliest libraries who brought async support to redis. `redis-py` however, took its time before it implemented async too, thus it got popular that way (tutorials and guides adopted the use of aioredis).Now focusing in what is the best library right now, my suggestion is redis-py (there is one even a lot better: redis-om). It keeps the simplicity of classic `redis-py` with async support (just need to specify that you want async, in your imports)

Comment: @SeanWilliam Hence, even [aioredis official github page](https://github.com/aio-libs/aioredis-py), suggests that you use the async module within `redis-py` instead of using `aioredis` itself. 
This is one of the drawbacks of tutorials, still a not a big deal, but it is good to keep in mind that they might be outdated, or not fully covering everything.
If you want a far more beautiful redis library, check [redis-om](https://github.com/redis/redis-om-python)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I was returning the wrong data it should be like this

```
# If cache is found then serves the data from cache
    if data is not None:
        data = data.decode("UTF-8")
        data_dict = json.loads(data)
        print(data_dict)
        print(type(data_dict))
        data_dict["cache"] = True
        return data_dict
```

and everything works fine.